# Настройка кэша в nginx.conf

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, кэширование

Всем привет! Google Pagespeed жалуется на то, что картинки, стили, скрипты не кэшируются. В файле htaccess все выставлено, но это не работает. Понял, что причина в Nginx. Как изменить код, чтобы включить кэширование?

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/vhosts/*/*.conf;
client_max_body_size 128m;
server {
    server_name localhost;
disable_symlinks if_not_owner;
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
location @fallback {
    error_log /dev/null crit;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 /;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    access_log off ;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить внутрь блока server ещё один location (вся "магия" в expires):

```
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|html|css|zip|tgz|gz|js)$ {
        root /var/www/html/public; #ваш путь к статическим файлам
        access_log off; 
        expires 30d;
    }
```